# Can not access mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I try to access the mysql database IDE raises
"Could not connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'smeeton'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"
error message. I tried every command I found here eg. " mysql -u root -p -h" but it always asks me the username and password or it does not recognize mysql keyword. I tried creating new user from SQL console but it does not allow me to do.  What should I do to connect the database_

**mysqli_connect.php**

```
<?php

DEFINE('DB_USER','smeeton');
DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD',"Lighthouse");
DEFINE('DB_HOST','localhost');
DEFINE('DB_NAME','estatedb');

$dbcon = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) or die
('Could not connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error());

mysqli_set_charset($dbcon,'utf8');
?>
```

Comment: does your user have the correct privileges?

Comment: the user has been provided by my instructor and he stated that no one had any issues so I think yes

Comment: isn't the third parameter in mysqliconnect the password field?? ```@mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassword,$dbname)```
and I notice you have a password so you should probably pass it as well?

Comment: I was just playing with it It does not work when pass the password too. Sorry for pasting it like that

Comment: Like mentioned, check the user privileges and hostname. The issue might be the host the user is allowed to connect from.

Comment: Where should I check that. I am using xampp.